# Scrapy is done running with results in the console but CSV output remains blank

Tags: python, csv, scrapy

I'm very new to scrapy so it's hard for me to find out what i am doing wrong in case of having no results in csv file. I can see results in the console though. Here is what I tried with:

Main folder is named "realyp".
Spider file is named "yp.py" and the code:

```
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from realyp.items import RealypItem

class MySpider(BaseSpider):
     name="YellowPage"
     allowed_domains=["yellowpages.com"]
     start_urls=["https://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=Coffee%20Shops&geo_location_terms=Los%20Angeles%2C%20CA&page=2"]

     def parse(self, response):
        title = Selector(response)
        page=title.xpath('//div[@class="info"]')
        items = []
        for titles in page:
            item = RealypItem()
            item["name"] = titles.xpath('.//span[@itemprop="name"]/text()').extract()
            item["address"] = titles.xpath('.//span[@itemprop="streetAddress" and @class="street-address"]/text()').extract()
            item["phone"] = titles.xpath('.//div[@itemprop="telephone" and @class="phones phone primary"]/text()').extract()
            items.append(item)
        return items
```

"items.py" file includes:

```
from scrapy.item import Item, Field
class RealypItem(Item):
    name= Field()
    address = Field()
    phone= Field()
```

To get the csv output my command line is:

```
cd desktop
cd realyp
scrapy crawl YellowPage -o items.csv -t csv
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you describe more exactly what you're expecting and how that differs from your result? It would help to phrase as a question too.

How is the file test.py used? I only see how items.py is being used from the command line

Comment: Thanks for your response, MrJLP. Actually I'm expecting "item title" in the first column and "item link" in the second column but as a csv output I am only getting the header name with no results.

Comment: I'm not familiar with scrapy. To debug you can put print out the value of "title" and "item" to see where the disconnect is happening.

Comment: I've tested your code and it writes the result on the file for me. In your case, the file items.csv remains empty or is not generated at all?

Comment: Thanks sir Tomark, for your reply. It does generate csv file but with no output except for the header.

Comment: Strange, it works for me. However, the result written on the file is quite chaotic, you should improve the spider. What exactly it is written to .csv file? What OS do you run? In one of the last lines of the console should appear the following text: "INFO: Stored csv feed (120 items) in: items.csv": Can you see it?

Comment: Could you post run log? via `scrapy crawl myspider -s LOG_FILE=output.log` or `scrapy crawl myspider &> output.log`. It might be that your items are never returned and are getting dropped in a pipeline or something.

Comment: also you should just `yield item` instead of adding it to an `items` list and then return that list - scrapy callbacks can be generators :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated by @Granitosauros, you should use `yield` instead of `return`. The yield should be inside the for cycle.
In the for cycle, if the path starts with // then all elements in the document which fulfill following criteria are selected (see [here](http://zvon.org/comp/r/tut-XPath_1.html#Pages~Start_with_%2F%2F)).

Here's a (rough) code that works for me:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from realyp.items import RealypItem

class MySpider(BaseSpider):
    name="YellowPage"
    allowed_domains=["yellowpages.com"]
    start_urls=["https://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=Coffee%20Shops&geo_location_terms=Los%20Angeles%2C%20CA&page=2"]

    def parse(self, response):
        for titles in response.xpath('//div[@class = "result"]/div'):
            item = RealypItem()
            item["name"] = titles.xpath('div[2]/div[2]/h2 /a/span[@itemprop="name"]/text()').extract()
            item["address"] = titles.xpath('string(div[2]/div[2]/div/p[@itemprop="address"])').extract()
            item["phone"] = titles.xpath('div[2]/div[2]/div/div[@itemprop="telephone" and @class="phones phone primary"]/text()').extract()
            yield item
```